# Escaping New Line character within SQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, java-8

I am reading a table using my java code and creating a csv file out of it. So the 4 rows that I have get converted similar to below -

```
sam , 18 , banker , He likes to play football 
jam , 28 , hacker , he likes nothing
```

However in certain cases when the last varchar2 column contains \n it becomes like this

```
sam , 18 , banker , He likes 
                    to play
                    football 
jam , 28 , hacker , he 
                    likes
                    nothing
```

When I try to read the file , each line is read one at a time and I'm not able parse the data due to few words being pushed to subsequent lines. Is there a way to escape the new line character within the column in my query to make it into a single line?

My sql query

```
select name , age , job , hobbies from person_details
```

I am using csvwriter to generate the csv file -

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(results), DELIMITER, Character.MIN_VALUE, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
```

I used the below to remove line breaks. However looking for ways to preserve them as well -

`replace (replace (hobbies, chr (13), ''), chr (10), ' ')`

Comment: Google for "Java CSV writer", and pick one of the CSV libraries that will correctly write CSV for you, wherever the data comes from. SQL is irrelevant.

Comment: That's not a valid CSV. Maybe you should fix it first using a pre-processor.

Comment: @JBNizet I am using com.opencsv.CSVWriter to generate the CSV, This is generating the file similar to what is listed above. I used this to convert resultset to csv.

Comment: That's not the output I get when using OpenCSV. It encloses each value into double quotes, unlike what your output shows.

Comment: @JBNizet I’ll check my output and see if it had double quotes. But it breaks the output into multiple lines and I store the result into a file. I read the file by line and parse each line. Since some of the rows are empty lines or contain unexpected strings without delimiter , it fails. Is there a recommended way of parsing data in my scenario ?

Comment: Well, don't do that. Use a CSV parser to parse CSV. OpenCSV also has a CSVReader.

Comment: @JBNizet , I tried this and this seems to work fine  ```new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(resultFile), CEDILLA_CHAR, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, ESCAPE_CHAR, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the CSV parser on the other side. They vary a lot in behavior as CSV isn't really standardized. But try to enclose the strings in double quotes.

```
SELECT '"' || name || '"',
       age,
       '"' || job || '"',
       '"' || hobbies || '"'
       FROM person_details;
```

But JB Nizet's comment has a point. It's probably the best idea to do the transformation in the Java code.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit. I'm trying to transform in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\n` while querying. Use the following query.

```
select name , age , job , REPLACE(hobbies,CHR(10),'') "hobbies" from person_details
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't recognize C-style character escapes such as `\n`.

Comment: I had to use the query in my updated question to remove the line feeds. however will try using csvparser as suggested by @JB Nizet. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `REPLACE` or `TRANSLATE` functions:

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, JOB, REPLACE(HOBBIES, CHR(10), '')
  FROM PERSON_DETAILS
```

or

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, JOB, TRANSLATE(HOBBIES, 'x' || CHR(10) || CHR(12) || CHR(13), 'x')
  FROM PERSON_DETAILS                         --     LF         FF         CR
```

`TRANSLATE` is useful if you have multiple translations to make. Here I've augmented the response to eliminate carriage returns, form feeds, and linefeeds in HOBBIES.